# How can I target all anchor elements with attribute "name" on a page with jquery?

Tags: jquery

Say if I want to target all anchor elements on a page with the name attribute

```
<a name = "about">About</a>
<a name = "contact">Contact</a>
```

to target each of those how would I do it?

Comment: The jquery documentation has a whole section about selectors. You should check it out!

Comment: Did you even looked at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/)?

Comment: sorry left out an important part - edited the question

Comment: Yes, look in the documentation for "attribute selector".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try with this

```
$('a[name]');
```

Comment: It would target ones without a name attribute